# Writing a unit test for searching record and sorting the record in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, feathersjs

Just new to writing unit tests , Just wanted to ask if what is an example of writing unit test for the example code below , like when to use assert ? and how do I test the filter in the code below ? THank you. I am using mocha on my uni test

#current unit test code

```
.....
      it('load the hook', () => {
        assert.ok(search, 'Load the hook');
      });
    
      it('searches for record and sort', async () => {
    
        const search_key = "Rajesh"
    
        const people = await People.find({
          query: {
            $limit: 25,
            $skip: 0,
            $sort: {
              'people': 1,
            },
            $or: [{
              name: {
                $like: search_key,
              },
            }],
          },
        });
      });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `search_data` method here? As I understand you are using mongoose in your unit test and sequelize in the `search_data` method

Comment: @Jumshud yeah both worked. I've tried it on my other unit test

Comment: search data is the method

Comment: So, you need to test only if `people` array filtered by `search_key` in the expected order or you also want to write a test for the `search_data` method?

Comment: @Jumshud aint the test should have the same functionality with search_data method ?

Comment: @Jumshud a test for search data Sir

Comment: Of course, if you are using `search_data` method and want to make sure it works properly you have to test it by calling that method. You shouldn't write another method/code with a different tool(mongoose).

Comment: @Jumshud can you provide an example sir based on the method I've provided

Comment: for sure, btw, you can simplify your search_data method like with mongoose if you have model. It will be more clean and short

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217664/discussion-between-jumshud-and-mark-latin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed I added test cases for checking filters by name and sorting. For sorting you can use chai-sorting package: `npm install chai-sorted`. You will need to adjust a bit the code according to the comments below. Hope it will help

```
it('searches for record and sort', async () => {
    const search_key = "Rajesh";
    const limit = 25;
    //you will need to have `data` variable and link `search_key` and `limit` with it somehow
    const people = await search_data()(data);
    if (people) {
      //length must be less than or equal to `limit`
      expect(people.length).to.be.at.most(limit);

      // check sorting by name. you can change it as descendingBy if you need
      expect(people).to.be.ascendingBy("name");

      people.forEach(person => { 
        //checking filter for name
        expect(person.name).to.have.string(search_key);
      });
    }        
});
```

Comment: NOTE: a unit test is supposed to be isolated/mocked and shouldn't talk to DB, global scope. We have integration testing for this purpose. For mocking a methods in a unit test you can use `sinonjs` library: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/mocks/

Comment: why it is not allowed to talk to db sir ?\

Comment: @MarkLatin because of the nature of unit testing. It is supposed to test a software unit/component without its dependencies. there is integration testing to test a few modules/units together. You can google about the testing pyramid. Here is some info about unit testing best practices: https://dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-best-practices-how-to-get-the-most-ou

Comment: how about functional testing ?